# My script can't execute Drop table command SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, drop-table

I have a script which has a DROP TABLE command like this:

```sql
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('msdb.dbo.lobloblob') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE msdb.dbo.lobloblob
CREATE TABLE msdb.dbo.lobloblob
....
```

this command execute properly. 
but in script the drop command doesn't execute and propose this error

> There is already an object named 'msdb.dbo.lobloblob' in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
IF OBJECT_ID('msdb.dbo.lobloblob', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE msdb.dbo.lobloblob;

CREATE TABLE msdb.dbo.lobloblob (...);
```

instead. I presume you are running this script from the context of a database other than `msdb` so it won't be in `sys.objects`